# Why is my CSP header middleware not working?

Tags: clojure, http-headers, ring

I've written a simple middleware function to add the Content-Security-Policy header to my API routes, I've tried using multiple policies (default-src, img-src, frame-ancestors) pointing to either 'self' or explicitly to "http://localhost:port" but none of these seem to work.

This is my simple middleware:

```
(defn wrap-content-type-security
  [handler]
  (fn [req]
    (let [resp (handler req)]
      (header resp "Content-Security-Policy" "default-src 'self'"))))
```

I am able to see the correct header set in my routes:
[image]

However I'm still getting the usual favicon.ico route error, I do have a dummy route for /favicon.ico just returning some text and this also returns the CSP header.

There's obviously something I'm missing/doing wrong, any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Edit: Looking more into this, seems like this is a Firefox related issue? I tried to replicate the issue in Chrome and everything seems to be working fine as the favicon does show in the browser tab.
[image]

However in Firefox, still showing the same issue:
[image]

Which makes me thing that it's got something to do with that "FaviconLoader.jsm" script? being loaded/shown on the console.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your middleware is working (adding the CSP header) but you don't have a proper csp header value.
Try adding `img-src 'self'` and see if it helps.

Btw. you can try `Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only` until you tune your CSP header.

Comment: I had tried both of these suggestions and unfortunately  neither worked.